# Aggregating data by start_date for value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts. I would like to group and aggregate by year and month and sum the values. The challenge being in my current output, I could only output the start_date and I would like to somehow show the end date which will be the last start date of the dict item in the list for that month and year. This is what I have tried so far.

```
from itertools import groupby

u = [
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-01",
            "val": 5436,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-02",
            "val": 5376,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-03",
            "val": 5608,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-04",
            "val": 5671,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-05",
            "val": 5800,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-06",
            "val": 5834,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-07",
            "val": 5800,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-08",
            "val": 5658,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-09",
            "val": 5709,
            "year_month": "2018-12"
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-10",
            "val": 5673,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-11",
            "val": 5661,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-12",
            "val": 5889,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-13",
            "val": 6197,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-14",
            "val": 6163,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-15",
            "val": 6376,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-16",
            "val": 5762,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-17",
            "val": 5733,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-18",
            "val": 6207,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-19",
            "val": 5600,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-20",
            "val": 5815,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-21",
            "val": 5533,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-22",
            "val": 5346,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-23",
            "val": 5478,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-24",
            "val": 5276,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-25",
            "val": 5205,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-26",
            "val": 5246,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-27",
            "val": 5234,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-28",
            "val": 5233,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-29",
            "val": 5102,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-30",
            "val": 5240,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2018-12-31",
            "val": 5248,
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2021-12-04",
            "val": 808,
        }
    ]

def yss():
    result = []
    for k, v in groupby(u, key=lambda x: x['start_date'][:7]):
        result.append({'date': k + '-01', 'value': sum(int(d['val']) for d in v)})
    return result

yss()
```

Output is -

```
[{'date': '2018-12-01', 'value': 174109},
 {'date': '2021-12-01', 'value': 808}]
```

I want the output to be

```
[{'start_date':'2018-12-01', 'end_date': '2018-12-31','value':174109}, {'start_date':'2021-12-04','end_date':'2021-12-04','value':808}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `groupby`, save the grouped data to a list of tuples and use this to construct your result:

```
result = []
for k, v in groupby(u, key=lambda x: x['start_date'][:7]):
    date_values = [(d["start_date"], d["val"]) for d in v]
    result.append({'start_date': min(d[0] for d in date_values),
                   'end_date': max(d[0] for d in date_values),
                   'value': sum(d[1] for d in date_values)})

>>> result
[{'start_date': '2018-12-01', 'end_date': '2018-12-31', 'value': 174109},
 {'start_date': '2021-12-04', 'end_date': '2021-12-04', 'value': 808}]
```

Alternatively, with `pandas` using Named Aggregation:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(u)
result = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']).dt.to_period('M'))
            .agg(start_date=("start_date", "min"), 
                 end_date=("start_date","max"),
                 value=("val","sum"))
           .to_dict(orient='records')
          )

>>> result
[{'start_date': '2018-12-01', 'end_date': '2018-12-31', 'value': 174109},
 {'start_date': '2021-12-04', 'end_date': '2021-12-04', 'value': 808}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(u)[['start_date','val']]
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['year_month'] = df['start_date'].dt.to_period('M')
out = (df.groupby('year_month').agg({'start_date':['first','last'],'val':'sum'})
       .droplevel(0, axis=1).rename({'first':'start_date', 'last':'end_date', 'sum':'value'}, axis=1)
       .reset_index(drop=True))
out[['start_date','end_date']] = out[['start_date','end_date']].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d'), axis=1)
out = list(out.T.to_dict().values())
```

Output:

```
[{'start_date': '18-12-01', 'end_date': '18-12-31', 'value': 174109},
 {'start_date': '21-12-04', 'end_date': '21-12-04', 'value': 808}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(u)
# Convert start date
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df["year"] = df["start_date"].apply(lambda x: x.year)
df["month"] = df["start_date"].apply(lambda x: x.month)

result = []
for (year, month), group  in df.groupby(["year", "month"]): 
    start_date = group["start_date"].min() 
    end_date = group["start_date"].max() 
    value = group["val"].sum() 
    result.append({"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date, "value": value})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is as a single nested comprehension, just for funsies:

```
>>> [(
...     lambda p=[(d["start_date"], d["val"]) for d in g]: {
...         "start_date": p[0][0],
...         "end_date": p[-1][0],
...         "value": sum(v for _, v in p)
...     }
... )() for _, g in groupby(
...     sorted(u, key=lambda d: d["start_date"]),
...     key=lambda d: d["start_date"][:7]
... )]
[{'start_date': '2018-12-01', 'end_date': '2018-12-31', 'value': 174109}, {'start_date': '2021-12-04', 'end_date': '2021-12-04', 'value': 808}]
```